# Python django html

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am with a doubt create the product class that has name, price, bar_code and the class of Sale that has product and price.

In other words, by adding a new sale, she will select a product. How do I get the value of the selected product and add to the sale price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question isn't exactly clear, let me see if I can help you out :-)

I'm assuming that you have a `Models.py` that looks similar to this:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Sale(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
```

In order to calculate the total of each `Sale`, include a [Model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/) to the `Sale` class:

```
def calculate_total(self):
    """ calculate the total price of Sale """
    price_list = list(self.items.values_list('price', flat=True).all())
    total = sum(price_list)
    return total
```

The above calculates the sum of the prices for all the products in `Sale`.

Comment: Thanks for the attention and your answer but one last question I can call this function calculate total in .html file?

Comment: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'values_list'